# Suggestion on permission set assignment batch?

Tags: apex, batch, permission-sets

I wrote a batch which gets the user and insert permission set assignment based on the permission set defined in the criteria.

Say i have 1500 user met the condition defined. So i have to insert 1500 permission set. when i run the batch i see the inset operation is performed in the log but when i check the count of permission set assignment it showing the count less than 1500 (around 850). There are no error. I checked each batch log and verfied.

Please suggest. What am I missing here?

Comment: How many DML rows happening. You cannot assign permission set twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PermissionSetAssignment records automatically deduplicate themselves. Most likely, the remaining users already had the appropriate permission set, so no new records were created for those users.